# post method with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

Hi all I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jquery-playground-forked-uw3xl)

I am trying to do simple post method on ajax but I have some difficult.

First of all I have 4 inputs (name, mail, phone and country), on select with some option and textarea.

```
    <form id="sendMessage">
         <input type="text" name="name" class="name form-control" placeholder="name" required>
         <input type="email" name="mail" class="email form-control" placeholder="mail" required>
         <input type="number" name="phone" class="phone-number form-control" placeholder="phone" 
           required>
         <input type="text" name="country" class="country form-control" placeholder="country" 
           required>
         <select name="theme" required>
           <option value="">choose theme</option>
           <option value="greenColor">green</option>
           <option value="redColor">red</option>
           <option value="blueColor">blue</option>
           <option value="otherColor">something else...</option>
         </select>
         <textarea class="textBody form-control" placeholder="Сообщение" rows="5" name="message" 
           required></textarea>
         <button type="submit" name="submit"  >Send</button>
     </form>
```

The scenario is following, when user will fill all fields I want to send all information to backend after submit button but something went wrong.

```
    $("#sendMessage button").on("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let isOk = true;

    let name = $("#sendMessage .name")[0].value;
    if (name) isOk = true;
    isOk = false;

    let email = $("#sendMessage .email")[0].value;
    if (email) isOk = true;
    isOk = false;

    let phoneNumber = $("#sendMessage .phone-number")[0].value;
    if (phoneNumber) isOk = true;
    isOk = false;

    let country = $("#sendMessage .country")[0].value;
    if (country) isOk = true;
    isOk = false;

    let textBody = $("#sendMessage .textBody")[0].value;
    if (textBody) isOk = true;
    isOk = false;

    if (isOk) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/Guest/SendEmailForContact",
      method: "POST",
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      statusCode: {
        404: function () {
          alert("page not found");
        }
      },
      context: {}
    }).done(function () {
      console.log(":asdfasdfasdf");
    });
    }
  });
```

Please help me to resolve that problem. Thank you

Comment: Trace through your code, line by line, thinking about what happens at each step.  What will happen when `name` is entered OK?  First `isOk` is set to true, great, that's what you want.  But next `isOk` is immediately set to false, no matter what!  Try some JS tutorials, or search for related questions here on SO, there is plenty of code you can read to learn how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ajax` never runs because you set `isOk` to false just before the `if` statement. A better way of doing this validation is to set `isOk` to true first, then set it to false if any of the values is invalid.